# Laravel 5.5 Update of Empty Date String Produces Data Missing Carbon Error

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

The update to Laravel 5.5 seems to be creating a few oddities for me.  Probably something I've screwed up, but these issues only broke with the new version - this same code has not failed in 5.4, 5.3, etc.  The bigger problem is that the error is not consistent on the same model - it fails on update, but works on store.

I have a date field called 'decom_date' on a 'prog' model with the $dates field on the model overridden to include 'decom_date'.  A user can fill out a form for a new 'prog', and skip the 'decom_date' field.  The model saves with no error.  If the user edits the same prog model with the exact same form, and leaves the 'decom_date' field blank, the following error occurs in Laravel 5.5 only:

```
message "Data missing"
exception   "InvalidArgumentException"
file    "/var/www/ipfast/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php"
line    582
```

IE Carbon is now expecting a format instead of an empty string *upon updates only*.  I can work around this with a mutator on the model like so:

```
public function setDecomDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['decom_date'] = $value ?: null;
}
```

No problem - this works, and I think will stop the new breaking 100%... but I worry when things suddenly break, especially as it doesn't seem consistent across the saves.  This pattern fails consistently across every model I have with dates, and these were not broken before update.

Anyone able to shed some light on this - or maybe just something dumb I've done?

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this behaviour. If your date is an empty string it always fails with your posted error, no matter if it is during update or create.

Normally in Laravel 5.4 and 5.5 the global middleware stack contains:

```
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
```

You can check this in app\Http\Kernel.php

With this middleware emptry strings shoul automatically be converted to a NULL value which Carbons handles properly.

What I can imagine is, that your decom_date field is not even present in the request data when you 'skip' this field during create ( Just check it with dd($request) all on top of your store method.

And if you leave the field 'blank' during your update method, the result is an empty string ( In case the middleware mentioned above is missing ... )

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  You are totally correct - with the middleware above, Laravel should convert these to null automatically and I shouldn't have a problem.  I wrote the app in L5.0 and thus had to do this manually, so I do *not* use the middleware.  Thus, this is not my issue.  I believe in previous versions the field was not present, but it is returned as an empty string now in both store/update methods.  Might be another LaravelCollective problem, but still can't explain the diff store/update.  Or perhaps something changed in the $request code.  Still no joy.